# XML sorting

Tags: xml, sorting

I have the following XML

```
<fields>
  <field position="4" tablename="Students" headername="First Name" fieldreference="FirstName" orderbydirection="ASC" />
  <field position="2" tablename="Students" headername="Last Name" fieldreference="LastName" orderbydirection="ASC" />
  <field position="3" tablename="Students" headername="Race" fieldreference="Race" orderbydirection="ASC" />
  <field position="1" tablename="Students" headername="Sex" fieldreference="Sex" orderbydirection="ASC" />
  <field position="5" tablename="Students" headername="State" fieldreference="State" orderbydirection="ASC" />
</fields>
```

I want to sort it based on the "position"

How can it be done?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Using what?  XSLT?  a bash script?  magic wand?

Comment: @Chris - Good edit.  This way the syntax highlighting completely breaks.

Comment: @Sean Bright- Your right... Sorry, I should roll it back and leave it completely unformatted.... GREAT IDEA....

Comment: I am storing the XML in the DB table. I am then retrieving it and reaching this node using
m_nodelist = m_xmld.SelectNodes("report/query/select/fields/field")

now i want to sort it in the code behind itself and save it back to the Daabase table

Comment: @Chris - I think you meant "you're right" instead of "your right."  Sean 2, Chris 0 :P

Answer (score 1):

See sorting with XSLT http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2002/07/03/transform.html

Answer (score 1):

**This XSLT 1.0 transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="fields">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates>
          <xsl:sort select="@position" data-type="number"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<fields>
    <field position="4" tablename="Students" headername="First Name" fieldreference="FirstName" orderbydirection="ASC" />
    <field position="2" tablename="Students" headername="Last Name" fieldreference="LastName" orderbydirection="ASC" />
    <field position="3" tablename="Students" headername="Race" fieldreference="Race" orderbydirection="ASC" />
    <field position="1" tablename="Students" headername="Sex" fieldreference="Sex" orderbydirection="ASC" />
    <field position="5" tablename="Students" headername="State" fieldreference="State" orderbydirection="ASC" />
</fields>
```

**produces the wanted result**:

```
<fields>
  <field position="1" tablename="Students" headername="Sex" fieldreference="Sex" orderbydirection="ASC" />
  <field position="2" tablename="Students" headername="Last Name" fieldreference="LastName" orderbydirection="ASC" />
  <field position="3" tablename="Students" headername="Race" fieldreference="Race" orderbydirection="ASC" />
  <field position="4" tablename="Students" headername="First Name" fieldreference="FirstName" orderbydirection="ASC" />
  <field position="5" tablename="Students" headername="State" fieldreference="State" orderbydirection="ASC" />
</fields>
```

Comment: I was able to do this using LINQ in 2 lines of code.

Thakns everyone

Comment: Dim sFieldList = From field In SortedFields.Descendants("field") Order By Integer.Parse(field.@position)

Comment: Actually here is the full code
Dim feedXML As XDocument = XDocument.Parse(sXMLDefinition.ToString())
Dim SortedFields = From field In feedXML.Descendants("fields")
Dim sFieldList = From field In SortedFields.Descendants("field") Order By Integer.Parse(field.@position)